# XLOOKUP / FILTER Function Combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a CSV file containing various data that I have set a **macro** up to run the following formula for in a second sheet.

(For reference the CSV file might contain 20 items [aswell as other data i dont need], all of which will have a Name, Serial Number and Location)

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$F:$F &"",Sheet1!$C:$C=B1, "")
```

where B1 would be equal to "Serial Number"

| Item Name | Serial Number | Location | Door Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Filter goes here) | (Filter goes here) | (Filter goes here) | (Filter goes here) |

i have a piece of text in B1 called "Serial Number" - my formula effectively searches column C in sheet one for the word "Serial Number" and then filters out all the answers to that question from column F.

this works perfectly for all the questions that are asked every time and lists out the data i require.

The issue i have some questions are only asked on some of the items, and although it picks out the answers, it doesnt put them into the correct rows of items (just lists them from the next row down)

i was wondering if i could combine some statements or nest an xlookup to say, first look for the Item Name, and then return the next answer to this question

EG: look for Item name, and then return the answer to the question in cell AH1

i dont mind if its a nested xlookup, or an if and filter combination, or any method as long as it returns it in the correct row

i have tried an if function combined with filter, but this results in a `#SPILL!` message

```
=IF(Answer=A2,(FILTER(Answer &"",Question=D2,"")),"Not Found")
```

ive also tried the opposite way

```
=FILTER(Answer&"",IF(Question=D2&Answer=A2,"Answer","False"),"Not Found")
```

ive also tried a nested xlookup

```
=XLOOKUP(A2, AnswerF:F, XLOOKUP(D2,QuestionC:C,AnswerC:C,""))
```

where D2 is the item name, and AH2 is the new question.

im happy to share the file with anyone if this helps and i hope i have explained myself properly.

thanks for any help with what i am doing wrong

| Column C | Column F |
| --- | --- |
| (Question) | (Answer) |
| Items 1 |  |
| Item Name | abcd |
| Serial Number | 123456 |
| Location | Kitchen |
| Items 2 |  |
| Item Name | abcde |
| Serial Number | 1234567 |
| Location | Kitchen |
| Items 3 |  |
| Item Name | abcdef |
| Serial Number | 12345678 |
| Location | Kitchen |
| Door Type | Wooden |

Comment: So what's in `AH2` and why can't you apply that as a second argument to your filter condition? `=Filter([output_range],([criteria_range1=condition1])*(([criteria_range2=condition2]))`

Comment: What would be your desired output from given sample data?

Comment: You get a`#SPILL!` error because there are formulas below your `FILTER()` formulas. Spilled arrays need empty cells below them to avoid the error. I'm not sure your macro and spilled array formula work together. Why not have your macro do the filtering and append your table with hard coded results?

Comment: @bugdrown where do you see mention spill error and macro?

Comment: my desired output would be for it to display the door type, but in the correct row of items. so currently my filter would give me the list of items, under asset name (because there are say 20 items, they just list down in each row) but the door type would then list in the top row for that column (for something thats not a door).  Effectively i need the formula to look for the Item Name and if it matches, then display the next instance of Door Type it finds in its same row. if it doesnt match just be blank

Comment: So if you'll search on Serial Number `1234567` what Door type would you expect?

If your data would be consistent, this may work when searching on the serial number:
`=INDEX(answer,XMATCH(serial,answer)+{-1,0,1,2},)` Maybe it helps you. This  would work on `12345678` for instance.

Comment: @P.b. macro is mentioned in 1st paragraph. Later: "I have tried an if function combined with filter, but this results in a #SPILL! message."

Comment: Gotcha, I must've overread.

Comment: @P.b to give more context. someone fills in a survey that i pull the answers from in csv and i then need to format in an easier way to read, so the serial number wont always be the same, but there will always be one. so effectively i need it to search for the word serial number, and then search for the next time it sees the "door type" and populate the field adjacent (which is the answer) i might be asking too much of excel in all honesty

Comment: Maybe this will work: `=LET(d,A1:B14,a,TAKE(d,,1),b,DROP(d,,1),r,FILTER(ROW(d),a="Serial Number"),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(r),4,LAMBDA(x,y,
REPT(INDEX(b,INDEX(r,x)-2+y),1))))
`